# Integration of $\sqrt{\sec x}$.

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

This problem is a challenge question given to me by my friend. He asked me to find

> $$\displaystyle{I=\int\sqrt{\sec x}}\ dx$$

**What I tried:**

Let $\sec x=u$. So $$du = \sec x\tan x\ dx=\sec x\sqrt{\sec ^2 x-1}\ dx=u\sqrt{u^2-1}\ dx$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \ \ \ \ dx = \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}$$Hence,
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt u}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}du = \int\frac1{\sqrt{u\left(u^2-1\right)}}du$$
From this point on I couldn't find any good substitutions. So I tried doing it by parts.
$$\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac1{\sqrt u}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{u^2-1}}du\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\int\frac1{\sqrt u}du
-\int\left[\frac{-u}{(u^2-1)^{3/2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt u}du\right]du\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}+\int\frac{2u^{3/2}}{(u^2-1)^{3/2}}du\end{align}$$

However this has got even more complicated and I really have no hint on how to do it. Please help me if you know the correct method.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: This integral leads to an elliptic one of first kind.

Comment: Some functions don't really have elementary antiderivatives. This is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From trigonometric half angle formula we have $\cos x=1-2\sin^2\left(\dfrac x2\right)$ and we get

$$\int\sqrt{\sec x}\ dx=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\ dx=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2\left(\dfrac x2\right)}}\ dx = 2F\bigg(\dfrac x2\bigg|2\bigg )+C$$

Where $ F(x|k) $ is an [Elliptic Integral of First Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)