Find the indefinite integral of $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)(1 - \cos(x))}} \, dx$
Yo! it's exams epoch and, while I was praticing with other exams, I've seen this problem in an exam of an university friend:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}(1 - \cos(x))} \, dx$$
EDIT:
The problem was this, sorry for the error =(:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)(1 - \cos(x))}} \, dx$$
obsolete:
As a bit of context, the last topic we've seen is "sine and cosine rational functions integration". I've got to say that I tried to solve it doing integration by parts, or doing this:
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos^{3/2}(x)\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)} - 1\right)} \, dx$$
but when I was about to do substitution, it immediately seemed to be complex and I surrendered =(
bitte hilfe

It doesn't seem that that function has an elementary primitive.

May not be helpful at all but the function to be integrated breaks nicely to $1/\sqrt{\cos(x)} +1/2(1/[1-\sqrt{\cos(x)} - 1/[1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}] )$. At least the first term is supposed to be an elliptic integral (not a closed form unfortunately) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3106219/145325

Fricas (called trough sage) says:- 1/2*((I*sqrt(2)*weierstrassPInverse(-4, 0, (I*cos(x) - sin(x) + I)/(I*cos(x) + sin(x) + I)) - I*sqrt(2)*weierstrassPInverse(-4, 0, (-I*cos(x) - sin(x) - I)/(-I*cos(x) + sin(x) - I)) + I*sqrt(2)*weierstrassZeta(-4, 0, weierstrassPInverse(-4, 0, (I*cos(x) - sin(x) + I)/(I*cos(x) + sin(x) + I))) - I*sqrt(2)*weierstrassZeta(-4, 0, weierstrassPInverse(-4, 0, (-I*cos(x) - sin(x) - I)/(-I*cos(x) + sin(x) - I))))*sin(x) + 2*(cos(x) + 1)*sqrt(cos(x)))/sin(x)

This seems to go through sage: integral(sqrt(y)/(1-y)/sqrt(1-y*y),y, algorithm="fricas") -((y - 1)*weierstrassPInverse(4, 0, y) - (y - 1)*weierstrassZeta(4, 0, weierstrassPInverse(4, 0, y)) + I*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*sqrt(y))/(I*y - I)

Applying the substitution $$t = \cos x, \qquad dt = -\sin x \,dx ,$$
transforms the integral to an algebraic one: $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x (1 - \cos x)}} = \int \frac{dt}{(1 - t) \sqrt{t + t^2}},$$ and applying Euler's First substitution, $\sqrt{t + t^2} = v + t$, rationalizes the integral:
$$2 \int \frac{dv}{1 - 2 v - v^2} = \sqrt{2} \operatorname{artanh}{\frac{1 + v}{\sqrt 2}} + C .$$
Remark The question originally asked about
$$\int \frac{dx}{(1 - \cos x)\sqrt{\cos x}},$$
and I'll include my solution here for posterity: Substituting $u = \sin \frac x2$ transforms the integral to
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{(1 - u^2)(1 - 2 u^2)}} \\
&\qquad= \int \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - u^2)(1 - 2 u^2)}}
    - \sqrt{\frac{1 - 2 u^2}{1 - u^2}}
    - \frac{1 - 2 u^4}{u^2 \sqrt{(1 - u^2)(1 - 2 u^2)}}\right) \,du \\
&\qquad= F(u, \sqrt 2)
    - E(u, \sqrt 2)
    - \frac{\sqrt{(1 - u^2)(1 - 2 u^2)}}{u} + C,
\end{align}
where $F$ and $E$ are respectively the incomplete elliptic functions of the first and second kinds.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x \cdot 2 \sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x \cdot \sin \frac{x}{2}}} d x \\
& =\int \frac{d u}{\sqrt{2 u^2-1}\left(1-u^2\right)}, \text { where } u=\cos \frac{x}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sec \theta$ , then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int \frac{\sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta}{\sqrt{2} \tan \theta\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \sec ^2 \theta\right)} \\
& =\int \frac{\sec \theta d \theta}{2-\sec ^2 \theta} \\
& =\int \frac{\cos \theta}{2 \cos ^2 \theta-1} d \theta=\int \frac{d(\sin \theta)}{1-2 \sin \theta} \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}(\sin \theta)+C\\& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the tangent half-angle substitution
$$I=\int  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos (x) (1 - \cos (x))}} = \int \frac{\sqrt{2}}{t \sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$$
$$t=\sqrt{1-u^2} \quad \implies \quad I=\int\frac{\sqrt{2}}{u^2-1}\,du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log \left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)=-\sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}(u)$$
Back from $u$ to $t$ and $t$ to $x$
$$I=-\sqrt{1-\cos (x)}\, \csc\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,
   \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\cos(x)}\,\sec
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$
